# how to display 2 different prototype cells at different different sizes

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

UPDATE:

I went a different route. Heres what I would like to do. Design my app that lets me save core data and view it in another console in tableview. Once in the tableview console, I can also see a chart at the top of the console as well.

What I did:

I created a UIViewController, dragged over an imageview just to use that as an example. I also dragged in a tableview, cells...etc.

My Problem:

I can view the blank tableview cells and see the sample image. Once I save the core data and go back to try viewing the data, I get an error. I have the datasource and delegate implemented but, do I need to put that in my code.

```
class ViewMealsViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<MealStats> = NSFetchedResultsController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchedResultController = getFetchedResultController()
        fetchedResultController.delegate = self
        do {
            try fetchedResultController.performFetch()
        } catch _ {
        }


        if revealViewController() != nil {
            revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 325
            menuButton.target = revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

            view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
    }


    // MARK:- Retrieve Stats
    func getFetchedResultController() -> NSFetchedResultsController<MealStats> {
        fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: taskFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return fetchedResultController
    }

    func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<MealStats> {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<MealStats> (entityName: "MealStats")
        let timeSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "mealtype",
                                                  ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))
        let milesSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "mealname",
                                                   ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [timeSortDescriptor, milesSortDescriptor]

        return fetchRequest
    }


    // MARK: - TableView data source
     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        let numberOfSections = fetchedResultController.sections?.count
        return numberOfSections!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let numberOfRowsInSection = fetchedResultController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
        return numberOfRowsInSection!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let mealstats = fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath) as! MealStats
        cell.textLabel?.text = mealstats.mealtype
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = mealstats.mealname


        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - TableView Deleteƒ

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let managedObject:NSManagedObject = fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
        managedObjectContext.delete(managedObject)
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch _ {
        }
    }

    // MARK: - TableView Refresh

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.reloadData()

    }


}
```

[UIViewController with a sample image for an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic8AT.png)

[Error I get once I try to view saved core data in the tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5GYm.png)

Comment: Yes, you can use a UITableViewController or a UIViewController with a table view.  You dequeue the cell using the appropriate reuse identifier.  Make sure you implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: got it working?

Comment: No but, I made changes to the project and went with a UIViewController instead of the UITableViewController

Answer (score 1):

Use UITableViewController

add two different cells to tableview on storyboard,

set two unique identifiers for them i.e

Cell No. 1 identifier : iden_1
Cell No. 2 identifier : iden_2

then in your class

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell
if(condition)
{
  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "iden_1", for: indexPath)
  let stats = fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath) as! Stats
  cell.textLabel?.text = stats.type
  cell.detailTextLabel!.text = stats.name
}
else{
  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "iden_2", for: indexPath)
  let stats = fetchedResultController.object(at: indexPath) as! Stats
  cell.textLabel?.text = stats.type
  cell.detailTextLabel!.text = stats.name
}


return cell
}
```

and use this for identifying height for both cells.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
if(condition)
   return 100
return 200
}
```

Comment: I fixed my problem. I had to add UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource even though I dragged the connecting outlets of the tableview to the view. Thanks for those who were trying to help.